# Trapped in implementing PCA: calculate mean in which dimension?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, pca

I'm learning [UFLDL](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/PCAWhitening/). Using the code in this tutorial

```
avg = mean(x, 1);
x = x - repmat(avg, size(x, 1), 1);
sigma = x * x' / size(x, 2);
[U,S,V] = svd(sigma);
xRot = U' * x;
xTilde = U(:,1:k)' * x;
```

I can get the result this tutorial requires (calculate k in another place, let's say k equal to 300). In this example, x is a n*m(784*60000) matrix, each column represent a MNIST image. In case I got it wrong, I've seen the code of loadMNISTImages.m which this tutorial prepared, it loads the mnist images as a 28x28x[number of MNIST images] matrix and reshape the matrix to #pixels x #examples.

From the code, I compute the mean pixel value and subtract it from each image patch, that is m(60000) means. And sigma is a n*n(784*784) matrix, so is U. xTilde is k*m(300*60000). So, this code calculate mean value for each image patch(each column) and reduce the dimension for each image patch(the dimension of row reduced).

Then I tried to implement a simple PCA example like this image shows:

[image: original data]

using code like this

```
x = [-3.8,-2.5;-1.2,-2.5;1,1.5;2.7,2.5;3,1.3];
x = x';
x = x - repmat(mean(x, 2), 1, size(x, 2));
sigma = x * x' / size(x, 2);
[U, S, V] = svd(sigma);
xRot = U' * x;
xTilde = U(:,1)' * x;
```

You can see x is a n*m(2*5, after transposed). I calculate mean value for each row and the dimension of row reduced.

Both of these two cases reduced the dimension of row, but the first case calculate mean value for column but the second for row. How do I understand this situation?

Comment: Are you saying you are surprised that transposing a matrix makes you use row-averages instead of column-averages? How is that surprising? It's basically the same thing.

Comment: understanding is simple - your first approach is wrong. You should compute **feature-wise** means, not **sample-wise**, thus you need an average for each "pixel", not for each "image"

Comment: But the first approach is exactly what the UFLDL tutorial says. So is it just a mistake in the tutorial or something I don't know?